# How to show download progress in QWebEngine?

Tags: c++, qt, foreach, download

In QWebKit I had this code:

```
QWebFrame * MainWindow::getQWebFrame(QString name) {
    if (getView() && getView()->page() && getView()->page()->mainFrame()) {
        QWebFrame * frameImLookingFor = getView()->page()->mainFrame();
            if (frameImLookingFor->frameName() == name)
                return frameImLookingFor;
        foreach(QWebFrame * frame, getView()->page()->mainFrame()->childFrames())
        {
            frameImLookingFor = frame;  at all
            if (frame->frameName() == name)
            {
                frameImLookingFor = frame;
                return frame;
            }
        }
        return frameImLookingFor;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

This is how it looks like in QWebEngine:

```
QWebEnginePage * MainWindow::getQWebFrame(QString name) {
    if (getView()) {
        QWebEnginePage *frameImLookingFor = getView()->page();
        if (frameImLookingFor->objectName() == name)
            return frameImLookingFor;
        foreach(const QWebEnginePage * frame, getView()->page())
        {
            frameImLookingFor = frame;
            if (frame->objectName() == name)
            {
                frameImLookingFor = frame;
                return frame;
            }
        }
        return frameImLookingFor;
    }
        return NULL;
}
```

Sadly it doesn't work. It shows many errors with foreach.For example "'i': is not a member of 'QForeachContainer". Is there anyway to rewrite this code, so it would work the way it did before?

Comment: What has this question got to do with showing any sort of progress? You're just enumerating frames...

Comment: well, in QWebKit this one was responsible for showing progress=\ When I put everything in comments, it showed nothing, but was downloading

Answer (score 0):

`QWebEngine` doesn't let you iterate subframes from C++. If you want to iterate them, you have to run some javascript.

What do you need these subframes for anyway?

Comment: Before it was working like this: If there's no file on computer, it showed red button. When you press it, it turns yellow (download is about to begin) and then it showed progress of download in %. After download was completted, the button turned green. Now it just turns yellow, and when download is completted, you have to reload page in order for button to become green

Comment: So, the page itself has some javascript that monitors download progress of something?

Comment: Yes. JS monitors download progress, but QT displayed it that way

Comment: You have to investigate how to interoperate between js and C++ in Qt Web Engine. There are some bundled examples for that IIRC.